# Python pandas loop efficient through two dataframes with different lengths

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes with different lengths(df,df1). They share one similar label `"collo_number"`. I want to search the second dataframe for every `collo_number` in the first data frame. Problem is that the second date frame contains multiple rows for different dates for every `collo_nummer`. So i want to sum these dates and add this in a new column in the first database.

I now use a loop but it is rather slow and has to perform this operation for al 7 days in a week. Is there a way to get a better performance? I tried multiple solutions but keep getting the error that i cannot use the equal sign for two databases with different lenghts. Help would really be appreciated! Here is an example of what is working but with a rather bad performance.

```
df5=[df1.loc[(df1.index == nasa) & (df1.afleverdag == x1) & (df1.ind_init_actie=="N"), "aantal_colli"].sum() for nasa in df.collonr]
```

Comment: could you post an example of how the to dataframes look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your description is a bit vague (hence my comment). First what you good do is to select the rows of the dataframe that you want to search:

```
dftmp = df1[(df1.afleverdag==x1) & (df1.ind_init_actie=='N')]
```

so that you don't do this for every item in the loop.
Second, use `.groupby`.

```
newseries = dftmp['aantal_colli'].groupby(dftmp.index).sum()  
newseries = newseries.ix[df.collonr.unique()]
```